# Add Transparent Gradient Mask to Cell

Tags: ios, swift

I would like to add a gradient mask instead of transparent to a color to a cell.

This should fade out the last line of text. So I added a UIView to my cells, and tried with:

```
       let gradient: CAGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
       gradient.frame = cell.gradientFooterView.frame
       gradient.colors = [UIColor.clearColor().CGColor, UIColor(rgba: item.color).CGColor]
       cell.gradientFooterView.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, atIndex: 0)
```

But with no success. How can I create a transparent mask?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it seems you miss locations, starPoint and endPoint of the gradient 
you can modify this piece of code accordly to your need

```
var maskLayer = CAGradientLayer()
maskLayer.frame = self.collectionView.bounds
let black = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
let clear = UIColor(white: 1, alpha: 0).CGColor
maskLayer.colors = [black, clear, clear, black]
maskLayer.locations = [0.0, 0.15, 0.85, 1.0]
maskLayer.startPoint = CGPointMake(0.0, 0.0)
maskLayer.endPoint = CGPointMake(1.0, 0.0)
yourview.layer.addSublayer(maskLayer)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try this, I have tested this in my code. I have just used the cell color instead of clear color.

```
    if let vw = cell.contentView.viewWithTag(11) {
        let gl = CAGradientLayer()
        gl.colors = [UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor, UIColor.yellowColor().CGColor]
        gl.frame = vw.bounds
        gl.startPoint = CGPointMake(0.0, 0.0)
        gl.endPoint = CGPointMake(0.0, 1.0)
        vw.layer.insertSublayer(gl, atIndex: 0)
    }
```